# whileactivity SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I am trying to use WhileActivity in a sharepoint 2010 workflow and every time a save or publish the workflow it will change the "WhileActivity" to "IfElseActivity". I have updated the web.config as well so the whileActivity is Authorized="True".

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
    <SequenceActivity x:Name="ID3" Description="Step 1">
    <WhileActivity x:Name="ID4">

            <WhileActivity.Condition>
                <RuleConditionReference ConditionName="__Rule_ID5" />
            </WhileActivity.Condition>

            <ns0:ClearArrayListActivity x:Name="ID7" ReturnValue="{x:Null}" />
            <ns0:AddToArrayListActivity x:Name="ID8" ReturnValue="{ActivityBind 
            ID7,Path=ReturnValue}" Value="DOMAIN/User.Name" />

            <ns0:EmailActivity x:Name="ID6" __Context="{ActivityBind
                ROOT,Path=__context}"To="{ActivityBind ID7,Path=ReturnValue}"
                Subject="yjfkg" BCC="{x:Null}" CC="{x:Null}" 
                Body="&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//
                EN&quot;&gt;&lt;HTML&gt;&lt;HEAD&gt;&lt;META NAME=&quot;Generator&quot;
                CONTENT=&quot;MS Exchange Server version 08.01.0240.003
                &quot;&gt;&lt;TITLE&gt;&lt;/TITLE&gt;&lt;/HEAD&gt;&lt;BODY&gt;&lt;
                !-- Converted from text/rtf format --&gt;&lt;P&gt;&lt;FONT SIZE=2
                FACE=&quot;Tahoma&quot;&gt;moo&lt;/FONT&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/BODY&gt;
                &lt;/HTML&gt;" />

    </WhileActivity>
</SequenceActivity>
```